# How do I get a random line from an external txt file?

Tags: python-3.x

So, I'm trying to answer a coding question. It's supposed to create a random knock knock joke from an external text file, but I can't figure out how to get the joke randomized. It just prints the first joke.

The below is my code:

```
# Saving filepath to a variable
# makes a smoother transition to the Sandbox
filepath = "KnockKnock.txt"

# When finished copy all code after this line into the Sandbox

# Open the file as read-only
inFile = open(filepath, "r")

# Get the first line and do something with it
line = inFile.readline()

# Write your program below

print("Knock-Knock")
print("Who's there?")
print (line)
print(line + "who?")
line = inFile.readline()
print(line)
line = inFile.readline()

inFile.close()
```

Any idea how to get a random joke instead of it just doing the first one in the file?

Comment: Better read and push all the lines into list , use random.choice to chose an random line

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file `KnockKnock.txt` has the jokes in pairs, every other line, then we can read *all* of the jokes into a list of 2-tuples, containing the setup and punchline.

```
import random
...
# read in file and make a list of jokes
with open('KnockKnock.txt', 'r') as infile:
    # make a list of lines from file
    in_lines = infile.readlines()
    # pair every line with every other line - setup and punchline
    jokes = list(zip(in_lines[0::2], in_lines[1::2]))

# choose a random joke
setup, punchline = random.choice(jokes)

# print the joke
print("Knock-Knock")
print("Who's there?")
print(setup)
print(setup + " who?")
print(punchline)
```

Comment: Using your code, Green Cloak Guy, I got the error
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    jokes = list(zip(inFile[0::2], inFile[1::2]))
TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @KadenReynolds Sorry, I mistyped the variable names within the `zip()`. It should be referring to the `in_lines` variable, which just made a list of all the lines in `infile`. I've edited my solution to fix that.